# mod_rewrite rule to use the CSS from root web folder in a subdomain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, subdomain

My root already has all the css and image files I require

- www.example.com (my domain)
- www.example.com/css/style.css (my styles)

On my hosting, my sub domain has to live inside a folder

```
root folder 
  public_html/
    index.php
    css/
      style.php
  subdomains/
      admin/
        .htaccess
        index.php
```

How can I use mod_rewrite in my subdomain to redirect requests for css into my root folder?

**FINAL SOLUTION**

Thanks! I used [Shikhar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/221220/shikhar)'s answer and modified it to also work with images and js.

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} admin.example.com
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [css|images|js]/(.*)\.(.*)
  RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} xyz.example.com

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} css/style.css

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]

This requires redirect though.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the box, why not just create a symbolic link from the subdomain folder to the root folder.  You should be able to do this through your file manager or though a shell prompt on the box.

Comment: This is good due to it's lower cpu usage, but can be a hassle to mantain, specially when adding servers.

Comment: @johnco: Thats what sh/phing scripts are for :-)

Comment: Doesnt mention if this is going to be deployed out to a lot of servers or not.  It could however be done in a script on the box as part of adding the subdomain.  You can even do it in PHP as part of the setup with `ln ../public_html/css` right in the PHP code.  Might want to actually check to see if the directory exists though before calling that a bazillion times ;)

Comment: Strange, the PHP back tick didnt come through on that comment.  That should surround the command there I listed.

Comment: Unfortunately this is on some cheaper hosting and so I don't have access. Which is why I am forced to have my subdomains in a seperate directory in the first place. Thanks for your discussion anyway!

Comment: You should be able to create a symbolic link via PHP.  I created a very simple PHP script to solve exactly the same problem as you on my last shared hosting server (which otherwise didn't have access to do it).  See the symlink() function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php